# PayPal Sandbox Code Integration IPN Problem with Asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I need your help regarding PayPal code integration with my asp.net/c# on PayPal Sandbox, I am using PayPal IPN and the code is same as provided by PayPal. I am working on local host. Payment has gone fine on PayPal and I have received the amount on my PayPal Sandbox account but when PayPal redirects it to my website page it shows me the following exception:

"Unable to connect to the remote serverSystem.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.10.9:8080 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() ".

I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: What exactly does your return page do? Is that the entire stack trace?